# How to I do a square root without using math.sqrt() in c#?

Tags: c#

When I run my program and put 0.00000001 to root nothing happens but when I put the whole number it runs fine. I'm expecting the method to work for decimals too. I also need a Message box with the message "Please enter a positive number when a negative answer is put in.

```
 private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumber.Text);
            double root = 1;
            int i = 0;
            //The Babylonian Method for Computing Square Roots
            while (true)
            {
                i = i + 1;
                root = (number / root + root) / 2;
                if (i == number + 1) { break; }
            }
 
            lbResult.Text = root.ToString();
}
```

Comment: "I'm expecting the method to work for decimals too." Then why are you parsing it to an `int`?  Does the method you use work with decimal numbers?

Comment: Converting 0.00000001 to an int in your first line of code results in 'number' equal 0.

Comment: In any case. this method cannot work for non-whole numbers because `i == number + 1` would never be true if `number` is a non-whole number greater than zero.

Comment: Is this a homework question, why would you ever want to do this and not use `Math.Sqrt`

Comment: Using `decimal` (rather than `double`) here is a minor waste of compute power. `double will give you aperfectly good approximate result (so will `decimal`, but at greater cost)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a Babylonian algorithm:

```
private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double number = Convert.ToDouble(txtNumber.Text);
            if(number <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a positive number");
                return;
            }
            double x = number;
            double y = 1;
            double tol = 0.000001;
            while (x - y > tol)
            {
                x = (x + y) / 2;
                y = number / x;
            }
            lbResult.Text = x.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm expecting the method to work for decimals too.

Then maybe don't do this with the input, and parse to something other than `int`:

```
int number = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumber.Text);
```

You want a `decimal`:

```
var number = Convert.ToDecimal(txtNumber.Text);
```